# modify link to _blank in upricing wordpress plugin

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

I NEED TO MODIFY THIS CODE _blank

```
  <a class='read-more' href='{$product['uds-link']}'>{$product['uds-link-label']} <span class='read-more-right'></span></a>
```

HOW I CAN DO THIS

very thanks

Comment: Felipe, please don't use CAPS (capitalized letters) in your question this way. It's like screaming. You can edit your question to change that.

Answer (score 1):

First off, please don't use caps.  Second, begging doesn't really push people to answer your question.  Thirdly, you're very vague.

Regardless, I assume you just want to do `target='_blank'`

`<a class='read-more' href='{$product['uds-link']}' target='_blank'>{$product['uds-link-label']} <span class='read-more-right'></span></a>`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it programatically, you'll need to use javascript. JQuery has a nice method called .attr(name, value) which you can use like this:

```
$(.read-more).attr('target', '_blank');
```

Find out more about the method at [api.jquery.com/attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 1):

Just change this:

```
<a class='read-more' href='{$product['uds-link']}'>{$product['uds-link-label']} <span class='read-more-right'></span></a>
```

to this:

```
<a class='read-more' href='{$product['uds-link']}' target='_blank'>{$product['uds-link-label']} <span class='read-more-right'></span></a>
```